# AngularJS construct JSON object for Delete

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, spring-mvc, controller

I am trying to construct JSON object to pass to REST API for delete . I am facing issues while calling the REST . I feel that I'm not properly constructing my JSON object . This is my AngularJS Controller Code

```
 var data = ["ABC","DEF"]; 
 var deletedata = [];
 deletedata = {"idList" : data}
 $http.delete('http://localhost:8080/services/delete/'+Systems+"", deletedata);
```

when i call my REST API the above way it fails . But when i call my REST API using ARC with JSON data like this It works

```
 {
 "idList" :["ABC", "DEF"]
}
```

while calling via ANgular whether i am creating my JSON object in a wrong way ?The Error i got on REST API is this

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the API expects jQuery type serialization of the URL parameters:

```
var config = { params: {"idList" : ["ABC", "DEF"]}, 
               paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike'
             };

$http.delete(url, config);
```